# Automatically Determine SMS Carrier-Provided Email from Mobile Number

Tags: mobile, sms, provider, sms-gateway

Is there away to automatically determine the [SMS carrier email domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carriers_providing_SMS_transit) from a mobile number?

(Similar to how you can look up a hostname from an IP address?)

Comment: And, this method would basically sidestep having to pay for a SMS gateway?

Comment: Phone number databases are not always up-to-date (sort of like how the paper phone directory can lag behind). For instance after a number is ported it might show up in a database as still belonging to the old carrier, even though calls are being routed to the new one. There's a reason email-to-SMS is free: it's a huge hassle and unreliable. You can take my opinion with a grain of salt though (check my profile) but just know I talk to many, many unsatisfied SMS email users daily.

Comment: The problem with using a third party SMS gateway is that those are often unreliable, as well -- offering only limited geographic coverage, for example.

Comment: OK so we've got gateways that are reliable and email to SMS that's unreliable. Sensing a theme here? SMS is unreliable, especially outside of the US. When an SMS email fails, how do you figure out who to blame? 

I think limited geographic coverage is not exactly accurate. We (and other gateways) successfully deliver numerous messages all over the world. Yes, some don't get through to some numbers in some countries. It's the exception, not the rule. It's the nature of the best.

Let's chat. Email me at jsheehan@twilio.com

Comment: Well, from the perspective of frugality, Phone to SMS-Email domain would save on the typical 1 to 3 cent/msg via SMS Gateway. Since both have rates of failure, it's nice to have both options open.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it appears to be possible, considering [these guys](http://mobilecarrierlookup.com/) are doing it. Not sure how, though. Also, Verizon offers a service to check their own network: [Verizon Wireless Network Checker](http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/LNPControllerServlet?path=lnppromo1)

Comment: Drats.. their API is still under construction.. Any idea how they did it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [NeuStar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeuStar) or use a Aggregator like [OpenMarket](http://www.openmarket.com/)

Comment: share your experience with them?

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that you can send SMS for free via google voice! Tested working for about a dozen countries so far (USA, Canada, Taiwan, Japan, Australia, China, France, Germany, Switzerland, UK) - likely others.

This would eliminate the need to use carrier-email checking to reduce spendings on third party SMS gateways.

Comment: API? I don't think Google offers this yet, but I could be wrong